# jquery select previous matched element that isnt a sibling

Tags: jquery

This may seem like a very amateurish question but I have a HTML DOM structure like this:

```
<div class="1">
    <div class="1a">
       <div class="1aa"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="1b">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to select to a `<div>` that isn't a direct sibling, for example:

```
$(function(){
   $('a').click(function(){
       // select div .1a
   });
});
```

I can't directly select `div .1a` because there may be multiple instances of `.1a` and I need to select the one thats nearest to the link.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use .closest(".1a"). That would pick the required div that is closest to the image.

Comment: Can you add the script to jsfiddle so that i can take a look at it for debugging?

Comment: I've figured it out now. I've done this...
`$(this).parent().parent().children('.1a');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $('a').click(function(){
     $(this).closest(".1a");
   });
});
```

.closest("selector") find the first ancestor of an element that matches the given selector

See http://api.jquery.com/closest/
for more info and examples

Answer (score 0):

Could you explicitly put the of the div that should be selected an put this id in the rel attribute of the link:

```
<div class="1">
<div class="1a" id="my-div-1">
   <div class="1aa"></div>
</div>
<div class="1b">
    <a href="#" rel="my-div-1">Link</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Your JS code will look like:

```
$(function(){
   $('a').click(function(){
     var selector = $(this).attr("rel");
     $("#"+selector).DOSOMETHING();
   });
});
```

This will work always and you do not need to think is the closest div correct one.

Jovan